# Relation between two problems of algebraic number theory

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, unique-factorization-domains

Consider the following two problems of Number Theory.

1. For which prime $p, \Bbb Z[\omega]$ is a UFD, where $\omega$ is a $p$-th root of unity?
2. Does Unique Factorization occur for infinitely many $d>0$ in the ring of integers of $\Bbb Q\bigl(\sqrt{d}\mkern2mu\bigr)$?

Both these problems are not yet completely solved. My question is

As both of the problems are concerned with unique factorization in a ring, is there any relation between these two problems. Does solution of one imply the solution of other? Also, what are the best-known results on these problems?

Comment: 1. is solved: this is the case if $p\le19$. See Washington's book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. It is a UFD for all primes $p\le 19$ and never again for any prime $p>19$.
2. The class number is conjecturally $1$ for infinitely many squarefree $d>0$ (Gauß), i.e., the ring of integers is a UFD for infinitely many $d>0$. This is still open.

Conclusion: The two statements are essentially not related. However, they are both part of the "class number one problem".

Remark to 1: The class numbers of $\Bbb Q(\zeta_p)$ grow rapidly with $p$:
\begin{array}{cc}
p & h_{\Bbb Q(\zeta_p)} \\
\hline
2 & 1 \\
3 & 1 \\
5 & 1 \\
7 & 1 \\
11 & 1 \\
13 & 1 \\
17 & 1 \\
19 & 1 \\
23 & 3 \\
29 & 8 \\
31 & 9 \\
37 & 37 \\
41 & 121 \\
43 & 211 \\
47 & 695 \\
53 & 4889 \\
59 & 41241 \\
61 & 76301 \\
67 & 853513 \\
71 & 3882809 \\
73 & 11957417 \\
79 & 100146415 \\
83 & 838216959 \\
89 & 13379363737 \\
97 & 411322824001 \\
101 & 3547404378125 \\
103 & 9069094643165 \\
107 & 63434933542623 \\
109 & 161784800122409 \\
113 & 1612072001362952 \\
127 & 2604529186263992195 \\
131 & 28496379729272136525 \\
137 & 646901570175200968153 \\
139 & 1753848916484925681747 \\
149 & 687887859687174720123201
\end{array}